# Can not compare Azure database in Visual studio 2022 schema compare

Tags: visual-studio-2022, azure-sql-managed-instance, database-comparison

I'm trying to compare the Azure SQL Managed instance to my local database project. But when I make a selection of the database "Ok" button is not getting enabled.

This used to work a month ago but all of a sudden it stopped working.

It's an issue with only one Azure SQL Managed Instance. We have one more Azure SQL Managed instance which is working alright(We can compare successfully).

And also it's just with Visual Studio, I have tried Visual Studio 2019 as well. We can compare alright in 'Azure Data Studio'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with MI. Fixed by manually editing SchemaCompare.scmp file. Just add your source module section:

```
  <SourceModelProvider>
    <ConnectionBasedModelProvider>
      <ConnectionString>Data Source=db.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=aaa;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxx;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Interactive"</ConnectionString>
    </ConnectionBasedModelProvider>
  </SourceModelProvider>
```